# not getting all rows beautifulsoup table, scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the course codes for all the course in University of South Florida (my school) and the Clep course equivalent

basically, I want the third column of the table.equi-chart in a list

Here is my code and I always get only the first 2 rows from this table

```
clep_url = "http://ugs.usf.edu/credit-by-exam/?page=exam&exam=CLEP"
page=requests.get(clep_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

rows = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':"equiv-chart"})[0].tbody.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    third_column = row.findAll('td')[2].contents
    clep_available.append(third_column)
    print(third_column, '\n'*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `rows = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':"equiv-chart"})[0].tbody.find_all('tr')` didn't work for me as well.

Here's what worked for me:

```py
clep_url = "http://ugs.usf.edu/credit-by-exam/?page=exam&exam=CLEP"
page=requests.get(clep_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all("tr")

for row in table:
    third_column = row.find_all('td')[2].contents
    clep_available.append(third_column)
    print(third_column, '\n'*2)
```

**Note:** `soup.findAll` is outdated. Use `soup.find_all` instead.

Comment: Thank you! had to do a minor change to ignore the first header row other than that it worked perfectly!